# Is there a way to draw a circle with the starting coordinates off screen in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to create a screen with a large semi circle background like the following image in compose.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1yLL.png)

In the XML based layout I was able to do it by scaling a circle to twice the width using layout_constraintWidth_percent="2" but I'm struggling to figure out how to do this in compose.  Is there a way to draw a circle larger than the screen and use it as a background?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/red_400">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/topGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You draw oval at 25% of height of your view and scale width by factor of 2 which can be done with Compose as

```
@Composable
private fun CircleBox(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier.drawBehind {
            val width = size.width
            val height = size.height
            drawRect(Color.Red)

            scale(scaleX = 2f, scaleY = 1f) {
                drawOval(
                    Color.White,
                    topLeft = Offset(0f, height * .25f),
                    size = Size(width, height)
                )
            }

            // Bonus Dashed line at 25% of height
            drawLine(
                Color.LightGray,
                strokeWidth = 2.dp.toPx(),
                start = Offset(0f, height * .25f),
                end = Offset(width, height * .25f),
                pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(
                    floatArrayOf(20f, 20f)
                )
            )
        }
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

Usage

```
CircleBox(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
    // Your Composables here
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: how can we rotate this view to show on bottom?